# Can't install executor

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, pip, python-3.4

I'm trying to download executor with pip, but I get the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking executor
  Downloading executor-1.3.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/executor/setup.py) egg_info for package   executor
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/executor/setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        readme_text = open(readme_file, 'r').read()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2842: ordinal not in range(128)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/executor/setup.py", line 25, in <module>

    readme_text = open(readme_file, 'r').read()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode

    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2842: ordinal not in range(128)
```

it is the 3.4 version, so it isn't a version problem

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12465446/489590

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Arch Linux.

Comment: what is the `locale` setting in your shell?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: does `sudo locale-gen LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8` work?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes.

Comment: and you still get the same error?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes.